# Reset Text in Combobox After Selection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox on my form.  It's in DropDown mode and it has autocomplete.  When it is first shown, its text is `"Choose part..."`.  I would like it to reset its text to this after a selection is made.  I've tried this (assuming the combobox is named `comboBox1`):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // [omitted]

      comboBox1.Text = "Choose part...";
    }
```

It only works when the selection is made using the keyboard (e.g. type a value and press `[Enter]` *or* start typing, use the arrows to select one of the autocorrect values, and press `[Enter]`).  When the selection is made using the mouse, the text remains the value selected.

I've had problems with keyboard & mouse doing different things with comboboxes before, but that had to do with certain events not firing.  I'm sure that this event is firing (the omitted code above runs regardless of the method used).

Has anyone seen this before?  Any solutions?

Comment: Trying to hide the fact that the user actually made a selection makes the UI pretty hard to use.  I suppose you could use the Leave event to restore the text.  Do consider just using a Label.  You could even put it on top of the textbox part.

Comment: @HansPassant The selection gets "copied" into another location (so the user knows they made a selection).  The problem is that I'd like to indicate to the user that the combobox can be used again for another selection, *without* affecting the first selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a delegate instead:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // [omitted]

  this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { comboBox1.Text = "Choose part..."; });
}
```

And as Hans commented, this probably is not considered the best UI implementation with how users come to expect a `ComboBox` to work.

Comment: Great, that worked!  Re expectations, see my comment response to Hans.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to add an item at index 0:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Choose Part...", "Choose Part..."));
```

then reset the combobox to item 0 after handling the ComboBox1.SelectedListItemChanged() event

```
ComboBox1._SelectedIndexChanged = 0;
```

The user experience issue here is somewhat ambiguous: there may be times when you want to reset the list to a "known good state".  For example, a user could be confused if the list remains on the previous selection.   Resetting the list box does give the user some sense that whatever action they intended actually happened.

Comment: The problem with using that extra item is that it will appear in the autocorrect, which is undesired; also, it must be explicitly ignored in the selected item changed event.